# How to find out which Mono application is currently running under OS X?

Tags: macos, mono

I have multiple mono applications running and need to programmatically (from bash) find out if a specific application is running.

I have about a dozen "mono-sgen64" entries if I look at Activity Monitor.

Is there a command/query I can run to know *which* of them is running which application?

Assume the application I am looking for is called "App1" and I am running it by running the following command in terminal: "mono-service2 App1.exe"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the ticket is:

```
ps aux | grep mono | grep App1.exe
```